# HTML/CSS How do I trigger another element when clicking :active or :hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Check out my JSfiddle right [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dcwn63a2/1/);
Now as you click on the red square it fills up, but how can I make it fill up the **green square when I click on the red square?** It's like clicking on an element and making it activate on something else?

I want to be able to click on something and then something other needs to do something, and not the same element, **without javascript,** is that possible?

```css
.red {
  border: solid 10px red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  border: solid 10px green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.red:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using CSS with the sibling selector: `+`, like this:

```
.red:active + .green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```css
.red {
  border: solid 10px red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  border: solid 10px green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.red:active {
  background-color: red;
}

.red:active + .green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>

<div class="green"></div>
```

Note that if the `.green` element does not immediately follow the `.red` element then you could also use the general sibling selector (`~`) too.

Comment: _"Note that if the `.green` element does not immediately follow the `.red` element then you could also use the `~` selector too"_ Only if elements have same parent and are direct siblings.

Comment: Only posted as to avoid confusion as to `<div class="red"></div><div><div class="green"></div></div>`

Comment: `~` only matches where elements have same parent and are direct siblings with second selector following first selector; not sibling ~ sibling child of sibling selector.

Comment: I know. My point is that you can use `~` in situations like the following fiddle, where the target elements are siblings, but have elements between them: https://jsfiddle.net/dcwn63a2/3/ Hence the statement about being an alternative when `.green` does not immediately follow `.red`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    .red:active + .green {
    background-color:green;
}
```

But remember, the green class element must be **after** the red one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could do this by using a class 'active' and `toggleClass()` instead of the pseudo selector `:active`

```js
$('.red').click(function(){ 
 $('.green').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.red {
  border: solid 10px red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  border: solid 10px green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.red.active  {
  background-color:red;
}

.green.active  {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">

</div>

<div class="green">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible but you will need to change the layout so that green is inside red.

Have a look at this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fed92oxr/

```
<div class="red">
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>


.red {
  border: solid 10px red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  border: solid 10px green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.red:active > .green {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to change the layout if you use the sibling selector as in the other answers